# Javascript add int to var name

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts

I want to add some data for a chart via vue to my javascript.
My Problem is that a don't know how many graphs will be gerenerated (It depends on the data)
Here is my Graph.js File.

```
import Chart from 'chart.js';
export default 
{
  template: '<canvas width="200" height="210" id="graph"></canvas>',
  props: ['amount', 'values0', 'color0', 'values1', 'color1', 'values2', 'color2'],
  ready() 
  {
    var datasetValue = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < this.amount; j++) 
    {    
      datasetValue[j] = 
      {
        fillColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0 , 0)",
        pointColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220, 220, 220, 1)",
        strokeColor : this.color+j,
        data: this.values+j,
      };
    }
    var data = 
    {
      labels: ['1s', '2s', '3s', '4s', '5s'],
      datasets : datasetValue
    };
    var context = document.querySelector('#graph').getContext('2d');
    new Chart(context).Line(data);
  }
}
```

Here my app.js File:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Graph from './components/Graph';
new Vue({
  el: 'body',
  components: { Graph }
});
```

and here my html

```
<graph
    amount="3"
    :values0="[3000, 3500, 4000, 6000, 1000]"
    color0="rgba(196, 30, 59, 0.7)"
    :values1="[4000, 2500, 5000, 3000, 2000]"
    color1="rgba(255, 125, 10, 0.7)"
    :values2="[5000, 6000, 1000, 5000, 6000]"
    color2="rgba(171, 212, 115, 0.7)"
    >
</graph>
```

At the Moment everything is hardcoded, just for testing purposes.
As you can see, I'm using the for Loop to add Multiple Graphs to the Chart. my Problem is that i don't know how to tell Javascript that it has to add the +j directly to the this.color and not the value in it, because i need the values from the html file (which are directly out of the database) and I don't know another effective way to parse them to javascript.

(I know my Code is a bit retarded, I'm new to Javascript...).

Comment: What are you intending `this.color` and `this.value` to be referencing?

Comment: Check the console for errors. You have several obvious syntax errors in your code which will prevent it from executing.

Comment: They are referrenced by the props array which gets its data from the html file which looks like this:
`<graph amount="3" :values0="[3000, 3500, 4000, 6000, 1000]" color0="rgba(196, 30, 59, 0.7)"></graph>`
at the moment I'm hardcoding the values, but if everything works I'll take the values from the database.

Comment: Nope, there are no syntax errors in my code @RoryMcCrossan because if i try it without +j and use a fixed number everything works. But that is useless for me, because I want 3 different graphs and not 3 times the same.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do something like:

```
var colors = ['red','green','blue'];
...
strokeColor : colors[j]
```

Comment: Because I'm also taking the colors from the database

Comment: @Insax So? Take them from the database and put them in an array. Job done.